# Address attribute remains populated for addresses bellow a address to whom it was assigned

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-address, address-attribute

An address attribute is created , let say **'test_price'**. This attribute is populated from front end. In case of more than one addresses,let say have two address with **entity_id 2000 and 2001** ,  **2000** is on top in admin and **2001** is bellow it,if I add some value for **'test_price'** for address **2000** from front end.When I go to admin panel, under customer address. For **2000**, it is added and displayed correctly, but for address **2001**, this is also being displayed in field.But in **DB**, there is nothing for address **2001**. Here if I **Save** customer,now it will be also added for address **2001** as this was being displayed in its field.Have some faced such a problem?, need some guidance.

**UPDATE-1:-** added attribute  **'test_price'** is being added in table

```
eav_attribute
```

with **backend_type** as **varchar**, So its data is being stored in table

```
customer_address_entity_varchar
```